# How to do Gmail merge with file attachment in one script. I have done my mail merge script but i don't know how to add file attachment

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

[This my mini project.Click here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c3tG1.png)

1. Gmail merge with 5 file attachments
2. Have to send email through google sheets with attachment
3. Must have email sent time
4. The requirements is in the image

this coding for mail merge in google sheets.I don't know where to add the file attachment and i don't know how to add.

```
function sendEmail() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1").activate();
  var lr = ss.getLastRow();


  var templateText = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Template").getRange(1, 1).getValue();

  var quotaLeft = MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota();
  //Logger.log(quotaLeft);
  if ((lr - 1) > quotaLeft) {
    Browser.msgBox("You have " + quotaLeft + " left and you are trying to send " + (lr - 1) + " emals.Emails were not send.")
  } else {

    for (var i = 2; i <= lr; i++) {
      var currentEmail = ss.getRange(i, 1).getValue();
      var currentClass = ss.getRange(i, 3).getValues();
      var currentName = ss.getRange(i, 2).getValues();

      var messageBody = templateText.replace("{name}", currentName).replace("{class}", currentClass);
      var subjectLine = "Reminder:" + currentClass + " Upcoming Class";
      MailApp.sendEmail(currentEmail, subjectLine, messageBody);

    }// class for loop

  }// class for function

}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Answer

To add an attachment you have to add a fourth parameter called `options` to the function [MailApp.sendEmail](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendemailrecipient,-subject,-body,-options). It is an object that can different advanced parameters. To define the attachment you can use the following example:

### Code

```
var options = {
  attachments: [file1, file2]
}
MailApp.sendEmail(currentEmail, subjectLine, messageBody, options);
```

However, I recommend you to use [GmailApp.sendEmail](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#sendemailrecipient,-subject,-body,-options). It is more integrated with `Gmail` and has more functionalities.

### update

The image you attach is a bit confusing looking at your code, however, I have edited it so you can see how to perform the task you want in a more optimal way.

Please check the value assignment carefully. As you can see, I only use once the method [getRange](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer)) and [getValues](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues) to get all the values of a particular row:

```
function sendEmail() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1").activate();
  var lr = ss.getLastRow();

  var templateText = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Template").getRange(1, 1).getValue();

  var quotaLeft = MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota();
  //Logger.log(quotaLeft);
  if ((lr - 1) > quotaLeft) {
    Browser.msgBox("You have " + quotaLeft + " left and you are trying to send " + (lr - 1) + " emals.Emails were not send.")
  } else {

    for (var i = 2; i <= lr; i++) {

      var rowValues = ss.getRange(i, 1, 1, 13).getValues()
      var name = rowValues[0]
      var organizationName = rowValues[1]
      var eventName = rowValues[2]
      var email = rowValues[3]
      //
      var file1 = DriveApp.getFilesByName(rowValues[7]).next()
      var file1 = DriveApp.getFilesByName(rowValues[8]).next()
      var options = {
        attachments: [file1, file2]
      }

      var messageBody = templateText.replace("{name}", currentName).replace("{class}", currentClass);
      var subjectLine = "Reminder:" + currentClass + " Upcoming Class";
      MailApp.sendEmail(currentEmail, subjectLine, messageBody, options);

    }// class for loop

  }// class for function

}
```

With all this information you should have no problem achieving your goal. If you run into any errors, let me know, but keep in mind that the code is not ready to use.

### Reference

- [MailApp.sendEmail](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendemailrecipient,-subject,-body,-options)
- [GmailApp.sendEmail](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#sendemailrecipient,-subject,-body,-options)
- [Sheet: getRange](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer))
- [Sheet: getValues](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues)

Comment: I need to attach a file that is pdf, word or sheet, for that I didn't get a coding to run.

Comment: To define a file to be sent later, you can simply use: `var file1 = DriveApp.getFilesByName('test123.pdf').next()`. Note that there may be more than one file with the same name in Google Drive, so you would only send the first one found. If you have further questions about the case, I suggest you edit the question by adding all the information about your context, what exactly you want to achieve and where you encounter a problem.

Comment: I have added my content in my question. Click the link to see the image

Comment: I hope my edit helps you to achieve your goal

Comment: I have made an update. pls look through this.